# Can't access the current position of UIImageView

Tags: swift, animation, uiimageview

I'v read many questions about this topic but their outdated or I can't understand them. This is the animation:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 20, delay: 0, options: [.curveLinear], animations: {
        self.SubmarineImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: (-self.frame.width - 80), y: CGFloat(Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.size.height / 2)))))
    })
```

How do I access the position of the SubmarineImageView during the animation?

Also these images show that the emitter cant update because the position dose't change

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ir8X.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DQyU.png)

Answer (score 1):

To access SubmarineImageView properties during animation, you can check it's [presentationLayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410744-presentationlayer). It can return nil, so you have to unwrap it first. To get a position during animation you can do:

```
if let presentation = self.submarineImageView.layer.presentation() {
    return presentation.position
} else {
    return self.submarineImageView.layer.position
}
```

Also, I'm a bit worried that you try to simply assign this value to emitter's position. That won't work, as the presentation layer's position is changing during animation. If you are trying to make it animate with the submarine, you should also modify the emitter's position in the animation block or add the emitter as a sublayer of the `submarineImageView`.

Comment: Xcode says that the SubmarineImageView dosent have a presentionlayer. So I added this for xcode to not have any errors: 
SubmarineEmitter.position = self.SubmarineImageView.presentationLayer.position 

@Dariusz Bukowski

It crashed... What am I doing wrong

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about layer in the call, I edited my answer, it should work fine now. The presentationLayer is a layer property.

Comment: Xcode proposes new suggestions to be able to run it. SubmarineEmitter.position = (self.SubmarineImageView.layer.presentation()?.position)!

That code crashes... What's wrong?

Comment: I edited the answer again. `Presentation()` can return nil, so you have to unwrap it first. I also made a comment about assigning this value to SubmarineEmitter.position.

Comment: This all is very difficult. Could you make a summary of the code. The code you left me in the answer leaves this error message: 
Unexpected non-void return value in void function

@Dariusz Bukowski

Comment: Please answer my respons

@Dariusz Bukowski

Comment: The error message you got is caused by the fact that you copied my example into a function that does not expect returning a position (because it is declared as a void returning function). To fix that you could for example define that position inline, like this: `let position = self.submarineImageView.layer.presentation()?.position ?? self.submarineImageView.layer.position`.
Giving you more examples is really difficult without seeing a bigger part of your code.

Comment: I don't have any code to support the movement of the emitter effect. In the update current frames I plan to call the emitter effects position to be the same as the submarineImageview so it looks like it follows it. I think you have a better understanding please help